# Long SQL statement fails in jTDS

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, jtds

My Android jTDS SQL client always fails with "**java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Connection reset**" when SQL statement is **longer than 800** characters. SQL has no parameters, just an "**INSERT INTO … VALUES (…)**". And absolutely same statement **works fine** when length is **less than 600** characters.

Please, help.

Comment: Does it do something different again when it's between 600 and 800 characters then? It might be worth checking what is actually running at the server by setting up an Extended Event. Maybe your application is truncating the statement.

Comment: Also, how can the statement be the same if it's a different length in characters? If the statements are different lengths they are inherently different.

Comment: INSERT INTO KEYVALUE VALUES(1111, 'abc...<more 500 chars>...xyz') - works
INSERT INTO KEYVALUE VALUES(2222, 'abc...<more 800 chars>...xyz') - does not

Comment: Same behavior (fails when longer than 800 chars) for all other SQL statements. I checked many times in different conditions.

Comment: Does the statement look ok in XE?

Comment: Sorry, what is XE?

Comment: Extended Events.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have the same issue.